# Do I need to use rectifier when my input source is wind power?

Tags: rectifier, bridge

Do I need to use rectifier in my circuit design when my input source is wind power to dc motor to generate the required voltage and current to charge a cell phone device?

Comment: Of course you do because the wind can come from any direction so a rectifier is needed to rectify that. *to generate the required voltage* that will not happen !

Comment: I think s/he means to use a DC motor as a generator. Usually the blades only turn one direction so output should always be the same polarity. The regulator problem is a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that your *generator* is a brushed DC motor being driven by the wind then you should be OK without a rectifier if you can guarantee that the generator will not be driven backwards.

You will have to ensure that you connect your generator the right polarity to your charger circuit. + to +, - to -.

> Do I need to use rectifier in my circuit design when my input source is wind power to dc motor **to generate the required voltage and current** to charge a cell phone device?

A rectifier will not regulate the voltage or current. You need a voltage regulator to control the voltage - typically at 5 V. The phone will draw as much current as it requires.